# PlayFramework 2.6: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing JSON from WS response wsBody

Tags: json, web-services, jakarta-ee, playframework, playframework-2.6

I'm trying to test a webservice. I'm using the class below to test

```
public class GitHubClientTest {
    private WebService client;
    private WSClient ws;
    private Server server;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        UMStateUpdate evt = new UMStateUpdate(2040, 0, 5, 0L, "CAR", false, "");

        // JsonNode tataa= Json.toJson(evt);
        //1-colocar esse serve la no webservice...
        //se funcionar o 1,então 2- testar novamente aqui se recebe dados certinho
        server = Server.forRouter((components) -> RoutingDsl.fromComponents(components).POST("/web").routeTo(()->{
            ArrayNode repos = Json.newArray();
            UMStateUpdate evta = new UMStateUpdate(2040, 0, 5, 0L, "CAR", false, "");
            JsonNode tata= Json.toJson(evta);
            repos.add(tata);
            return ok(repos);
        }).build());

        ws = WSTestClient.newClient(server.httpPort());
        client =  new services.WebService(ws);
        client.baseUrl="";
        System.out.print(server.httpPort());
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws IOException {
        try {
            ws.close();
        }
        finally {
            server.stop();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void repositories() throws Exception {
        JsonNode repos = client.unidademoveis().toCompletableFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // assertThat(repos, hasItem("/Hello-World"));
        System.out.println(repos);
    }
}
```

However, when using POST (.POST ("/ web"). RouteTo (()) I get this error java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing JSON of WS wsBody response

But when using GET (.GET ("/ web").) RouteTo (() -) works normally, what can it be? I want to use post because it is a webservice where I will always post to be sending data. I help

Comment: Please use english as language for your question since this is an international platform.

Comment: @GeorgHenkel altered language. Please help me